# column values are always truncated

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I am currently working on a little project where I stream machine data (JSON format) from a kafka topic for further analysis.

The JSON from the column values shall be split into multiple columns with their corresponding values. Now I always have the problem that I do not see all data in the column values, the view seems to always be truncated.

Reading the stream:

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "20.86.42.36:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "machine1")
  .load()

display(df)
```

Result:
[Dataframe with base64 encoded message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ipuv.jpg)

My first problem was that I received the data in binary, which I resolved by casting it to string, using this code:

```
val df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLPm6.png)

Now I still have the problem that I do not see the full column values which makes it hard for me to transform the JSON data into single columns.

I used `display(df1)` to print the dataframe.

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add example json?

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.show(False)` to print without truncation.

I suspect that the display function is similar.

Also, you've not base64 decoded anything. Casting to a string didn't return JSON, only deserialized UTF8 bytes from the topic (databricks may show that as Base64 via the display function, but that's not what's actually in Kafka if simply casting returned JSON)

Comment: `display` will try to show the full value if you move mouse over of the specific cell.